# Mixed language url's by TYPO3 & RealURL

Tags: typo3, realurl

I have setup RealURL for generating the url's but it is generating mixed language url's after changing the language. After clearing cache and don't changing language the urls stay in the active language, no problem. But after changing the language the url's become mixed. The language preset and page name stay correct but the description is a mix between two languages. For example the link urls below are generated on the same page:

```
/de/anzeige/kategorie/1/vorrat/all.html (this is correct)
/de/anzeige/categorie/1/voorraad/all.html (mix between german & dutch)
```

Looks like a cached problem? I fixed it now by making all combination between the languages in the realurl config file, but this makes the file to complex.

In the realurl config file I'm using the following code in the beginning to do the languages selection:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1, 2);

if($lang=='de') {
    $cat = 'kategorie';
    $alias = 'COALESCE(name_de, name_en, name_nl)';
}
else {
    $cat = 'categorie';
    $alias = 'COALESCE(name_nl, name_en, name_de)';
}
```

This part is used in the postVarSets to get the category name from the database. Could it a problem on how I get the category name from the database?

```
$cat => array(
     array (
         'GETvar' => 'extension[catname]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array (
                        'table' => 'database_table',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'uid',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => '1',
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array (
                            'strtolower' => '1',
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array (
                    'GETvar' => 'extension[catname]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array (
                        'table' => 'database_table',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => $alias,
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => '1',
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array (
                            'strtolower' => '1',
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                    ),
               ),
         ),
   ),
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not create a translation of your actual page in the page tree. The language identifier is still "de" in both of your links. So first step is to create a translation.

Next step is to make your extension support multiple languages, which will add some `language_*` fields to your table. If done correctly, you can created translations of your categories without having multiple languages in one database record. You will end up with having one record per language.

Next, you need to add the language config to your realurl config like in the [news extension](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news):

```
    array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                ),
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                'autoUpdate' => 1,
                'expireDays' => 180,
            ),
        ),
```

Then you're done :-)

Comment: But what should be the `cat` value? Or should a copy this array for every language with it's own cat value?

Comment: It's the cat value that is not corresponding with the selected language.

Comment: No copy (of course). Please take a look into the structure of the news extension. There are categories used the same way you want them to (I guess). The news extension also provides a [sample config](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Administration/Realurl/Index.html) where you can find a solution for your category problem. But as stated in the answer, you have to do the other steps before.

Comment: But it goes already wrong with the name `kategorie` and `categorie`. This name is not coming form the database but from the realurl config file. For me it is not clear how to set array name according to the language? Or is this not possible? Thanks already.

Comment: The use of "kategorie/1" should be necessary. Instead, if loaded from the database, the (translated) name of the category should be there. Assumed you have categories named "fruits" and "vegetables", those should replace the "kategorie/1" part. => `/de/anzeige/fruits/vorrat/all.html`

Comment: I have added a database table for the translation fields but still don't know how this changes the $cat (this case the value Kategorie) field? So I'm getting the correct name from the database but then the url wil be `/de/anzeige/kategorie/fruits/vorrat/all.html'. How can we remove the name `/kategorie/` from the url as this is fixed in my config file?

Comment: The keyword is "fixedPostVars", like described in this [blog post](http://www.verkon.de/agentur/neues/artikel/url_pfadsegmente_in_typo3_mit_realurl_entfernen/) (in German).